# Is there logitech gaming mouse programming software for any Linux Distro?

Tags: fedora, mouse, free-software

I happened upon an unopened Logitech G502 programmable gaming mouse. I would like to program buttons to do things like write commonly used lines in programs (which I know is possible in Windows; my college roommate did it earlier this year). The problem is, the device is meant to be programmed by software designed explicitly for Windows. The [website download](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/support/g502-proteus-core-tunable-gaming-mouse?section=downloads) page only offers versions for different versions of Windows.

A quick Google search yields nothing useful. Does anyone know if there is Linux/Unix software available for programming the mouse? I am using Fedora 20, but knowledge of any software for this mouse which will run on a Linux OS would be useful. The mouse's defaults work when simply plugged in (scroll, clicking/moving pointer, and page fwd/bkwd).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortly after asking this, I found the site below (wont let me link), which is written for a debian distro, but the concepts worked for Fedora!

http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Mice-and-Pointing-Devices/Guide-for-setup-Performance-MX-mouse-on-Linux-with-KDE/td-p/517167

The link above died, [here's a working archive.org link](http://web.archive.org/web/20160604141354/http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Mice-and-Pointing-Devices/Guide-for-setup-Performance-MX-mouse-on-Linux-with-KDE/td-p/517167)

Comment: Aw, this link died. It now redirects to https://community.logitech.com/s/ :(

Answer (score 1):

For this particular mouse, there are two options:

1. You can program it fully in Windows but store its' profiles on the device's memory. This makes for an operating system agnostic configuration.
2. Secondly, assuming you do not dual boot, you can use the [Piper Mouse Configuration utility](https://github.com/libratbag/piper), which is a front-end to the [libratbag](https://github.com/libratbag/libratbag) DBUS daemon.

Details on setting up libratbag and Piper are in the links pointing to their respective project pages.